# true dando problema(bug) no código

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp

Boa noite galera, eu tava desenvolvendo um script em php e quando coloquei o true sendo passado por parâmetro para uma função para dentro de um array de forma dinâmica , ele dava um bug. 
Não sei explicar o bug direito, mas a função funciona praticamente igual ao `array_unique`. se colocado `true` ele age como o `array_unique`, se falso ele simplesmente repete o que lhe foi passado.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
function random_caractere_v2($veredito) {
                 if($veredito) {
                    $elemento = func_get_args();
                    $array = array();
                    foreach ($elemento as $indice => $valor) {
                        if(in_array($valor, $array)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if(!in_array("$valor", $array)) {
                            $array[] = $valor;

                        }
                    }
                    print_r($array);
                 }
                 if(!$veredito) {
                     $elemento = func_get_args();
                     print_r($elemento);
                 }
              }


random_caractere_v2(true,'lapiseira','colchao','caderno','quimica','quimica');
```

Eu consegui resolver o problema usando o unset para tirar o indice que causava problema, mas to curioso para descobrir o porque do bug.

Comment: E qual é o bug?

Comment: o bug é que só passa o valor 1 que seria o 1 do true. o resto dos valores n passa , a condição é que se o valor já estiver no vetor array ele pule a atribuição e vá para a condição de baixo que é : se o valor não foi encontrado no vetor array o atribua então, mas o codigo n faz isso , fica preso na primeira condição , como se o valor já estivesse dentro do vetor

Comment: realmente muito estranho.. trocando !in_array para !isset aqui funcionou normal, vou dar uma pesquisa para entender o motivo deste erro

Comment: eu só consegui resolver , usando a funçao unset no indice 0 do vetor

Comment: Para mim não é claro o que a função é suposto fazer. Era preferivel que desse um ou dois exemplos de valores de entrada e saida, para se perceber o objetivo do código e depois então partir para a resolução do problema.

Comment: com o true ele ira retornar [0] => lapiseira [1] =>colchao [2] =>caderno [3] => quimica

Comment: com o false ela retorna a mesma coisa que foi passada , sem tirar o valor repetido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na função [func_get_args](http://php.net/func_get_args). Ela pega todos os argumentos passados para a sua função, inclusive o booleano inicial. Voce tem q remover esse booleano do seu array e depois trabalhar soh com os elementos novos.

```
function random_caractere_v2($veredito) {
    if ($veredito) {
        $elemento = func_get_args();
        // remove o primeiro elemento
        array_shift($elemento);

        $array = array();
        foreach ($elemento as $indice => $valor) {
            if(in_array($valor, $array)) {
                continue;
            }

            $array[] = $valor;
        }

        print_r($array);
    }

    if (!$veredito) {
        $elemento = func_get_args();
        // remove o primeiro elemento
        array_shift($elemento);
        print_r($elemento);
    }
}
```

Mas, outra forma de fazer é, a partir do PHP 5.6, usar o operador `...`, onde você pode definir os argumentos fixos e depois o que for variável. Por exemplo:

```
function random_caractere_v2($veredito, ...$elements) {
    if ($veredito) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($elements as $idx => $value) {
            if (in_array($value, $array)) {
                continue;
            }

            $array[] = $value;
        }

        return $array;
    }

    return $elements;
}
```

Que vai fazer a mesma coisa que a outra função faz, mas de forma mais elegante.

Comment: tipo , eu tinha resolvido excluindo o valor boleano , mas n sabia desse operador ... mas tenho uma duvida , vou ter que passar os outros valores como um array ?

Comment: Nao, passa os valores como argumentos, assim como no exemplo que você passou. O PHP se vira para transformar eles num array.

Comment: cara nunca tinha ouvido falar desse operador ... , aonde posso encontrar algo sobre ele ? , pesquiso no google , mas n acho nada

Comment: Na documentação do PHP tem sobre [variable arg list](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new)

Comment: vlw , bem mais rapido do que o func_get_args kkkkkk